# Hartshorne Exercise 2.6: what gradation does $S(Y)_{x_i}$ inherit from $S$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, graded-rings

Let $S=k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ be the "homogeneous polynomial ring" of $\mathbb P^n$ and let $S(Y)_{x_i}$ denote the localization at the image of $x_i\in S(Y)$ of $S(Y)=S/I(Y)$. In Hartshorne, he asks us to identify a certain ring with the subring of $S(Y)_{x_i}$ consisting of degree-0 elements.

My question is - what grading should these elements be degree zero with respect to? I know that the quotient inherits a natural grading $$S/I=\bigoplus_{d\geq 0}(S_d+I)/I,$$ but I don't know how the localization inherits its grading - in particular, how can we make sense of what has degree zero when we can divide by powers of $x_i$?

Comment: A fraction $f/x_i^n$ where $f$ is homogenous of degree $d$ has a naturally defined degree itself. Can you guess what it is?

Comment: @Arthur Presumably $d-n$. Thus an "element of degree zero" in said ring is any homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ divided by $x_i^d$? In this case I might be able to see the required isomorphism.

Comment: That's exactly it. In fact I think he spells this out in the very next section, although of course by then it's too late. In general if you have a graded ring $S$ and a set of homogeneous elements $T$ then it makes sense to put a grading on $T^{-1}S$, and this comes up a lot because projective schemes come up a lot.